# Exporting empty fields as NULL

Tags: qgis, table, null

I am using QGIS 3.4 and I work with a shapefile and its Attribute Table with a few rows where some fields are just blank (no zero value or `NULL`).

When I export the shapefile file to ArcGIS Pro all the blank fields become zero but they should be `NULL`. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Use a format that supports NULLs, for starters. dBase-III format was created in the 1980s, so shapefile doesn't support NULL attributes, only Null geometries.

Comment: See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005600000013000000.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but I just found how to solve it.

Here is the solution

1. Open attributes table
2. Using 'select by expression' function, select rows containing null values of a column
3. Enable 'edit' mode
4. You will now find editing engine in the tool bar
5. Select the column that contains null values that you want to preserve
6. write null in the editing engine
7. Go to the right end of the editing engine and click the button called 'update the selected'
8. Now the null values become 'actual null(empty) value' rather than string value with characters(alphabets) 'NULL'

So, the null values you have are not actually empty value but character values of 'NULL'. -->  AGAIN they are not empty so they changed to 0 when you refactor and export it